# Add a Count field to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `dat`:

```
        > dat
  subjectid variable
1      1234 12
2      1234 14
3      2143 19
4      3456 12
5      3456 14
6      3456 13
```

How do I add another column which shows the count of each unique `subjectid`?

```
ddply(dat,.(subjectid),summarize,quan_95=quantile(variable,0.95),uniq=count(unique(subjectid)))
```

Comment: Does it have to be `plyr` solution?

Comment: Nope any method works ....

Comment: See `?ave`: `ave(DF$subjectid, DF$subjectid, FUN = length)`

Comment: @josilber, this is definitely a duplicate, but the Q & A you identified is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach via `dplyr`.  First we group by `subjectid`, then use the function `n()` to count number of rows in each group:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
subjectid variable
1      1234 12
2      1234 14
3      2143 19
4      3456 12
5      3456 14
6      3456 13")

library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(subjectid) %>%
  mutate(count = n())

  subjectid variable count
1      1234       12     2
2      1234       14     2
3      2143       19     1
4      3456       12     3
5      3456       14     3
6      3456       13     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `ave()`, you may also use split/lapply/unsplit:

```
i = split(dat$variable, dat$subjectid)
count = unsplit(lapply(i, length), dat$subjectid)
```

Then graft the `count` variable back using `data.frame()` or whatever your preferred method.

---

The `split()` function just creates a list of `dat$variable` values for each value of `dat$subjectid`.  The count is found by using `lapply()` to apply the `length()` function over each index in the list (i) and `unsplit()` puts everything back in order.

`unsplit()` is pure magic and fairy dust. I didn't believe it the first 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

If dat is ordered by `subjectid`

```
   tbl <- table(dat[,1])
    transform(dat, count=rep(tbl, tbl))
   # subjectid variable count
   #1      1234       12     2
   #2      1234       14     2
   #3      2143       19     1
   #4      3456       12     3
   #5      3456       14     3
   #6      3456       13     3
```